# Create observable returning other observables as a single map

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I have an own binding for *`numeric`* inputs made in `knockoutJS` which accepts only numbers.

To make big numbers I declare various instances of number in a `NumberField` like:

```
var NumberField = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.maskFormat = "0";
  self.firstNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.secondNumber = ko.observable("");
  self.thirdNumber = ko.observable("");
};
```

And

```
<input id="0" maxlength="1" type="tel" data-bind="numeric: firstNumber">
<input id="1" maxlength="1" type="tel" data-bind="numeric: secondNumber">
<input id="2" maxlength="1" type="tel" data-bind="numeric: thirdNumber">
```

This is working like a charm, but when I made submission, system is expecting a map with numbers. I achieved it IMHO in an ugly way:

Added to `NumberField` this attribute:

```
this.cleanNumber = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return this.firstNumber().toString() + this.secondNumber().toString() + this.thirdNumber().toString();
}, this);
```

And in the code, when I need to use it I must do this:

```
let unwrapNumbers = this.numbers().cleanNumber().split("").map(function (item){
    return Number(item);
});
```

This is working, but... I'm pretty sure there is an easier and more straight way.... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could help to split the computed in to two parts:

1. Getting the numbers you want to include *in order*
2. Creating a string based on the ordered values

Often it makes sense to split a computed in to several pure computeds that have a single clear data processing responsibility.

```js
var NumberField = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.firstNumber = ko.observable(1);
  self.secondNumber = ko.observable(2);
  self.thirdNumber = ko.observable(3);
  
  self.orderedNumbers = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return [self.firstNumber,
            self.secondNumber,
            self.thirdNumber].map(ko.unwrap);
  });
  
  self.cleanedNumber = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.orderedNumbers().join("");
  });
};

var nf = new NumberField();

// If you want the numbers:
console.log(nf.orderedNumbers());

// If you want the string
console.log(nf.cleanedNumber());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Now, I'm not sure what your requirements are, but you can take it one step further and use an `observableArray` as the base data format:

```js
var NumberField = function () {
  var self = this;
  
  self.numbers = ko.observableArray(
    [ko.observable(0), ko.observable(1), ko.observable(2)]);
  
  self.add = function() {
    self.numbers.push(ko.observable(self.numbers().length)); 
  }
  
  self.unwrappedNumbers = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.numbers().map(ko.unwrap);
  });
  
  self.cleanedNumber = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.unwrappedNumbers().join("");
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new NumberField());
```

```css
label { display: block }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: numbers">
  <label>
    <span data-bind="text: 'Number ' + $index()"></span>
    <input type="number" data-bind="textInput: $parent.numbers()[$index()]">
  </label>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: add">add</button>

<pre>
Unwrapped:<code data-bind="text: unwrappedNumbers"></code>
Cleaned:<code data-bind="text: cleanedNumber"></code>
</pre>
```

Comment: `.map(ko.unwrap);` was what I was looking for... `:)`